# hood.ie login on multiple devices and sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoodie

I'm using hood.ie to create an web app.
The app will be shown on 2 iPad screens, and hosted from a laptop.

I wanted to ask whats the most convenient way to login. So for example as I see at the moment, I would need to log in to all 3 devices (laptop and the 2 devices) to be able to use lines like:

```
hoodie.store.on("change", refresh);
```

And on that a second question I find that `hoodie.store.on("change", refresh);` works at times however does not on others. Is there any specific implementation I should follow to that or is it ok just to place anywhere in my js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in is necessary for syncing, otherwise Hoodie wouldn't know whose data to sync to the devices, and how to only show the current user what they're allowed to see. Hoodie data is private by default, everyone's data is hidden from everyone else, so the only way to fetch someone's data is by signing in. So if you have multiple users, they'll have to log in on all devices so Hoodie knows which data to load for whom.

However, if you only have one user, and this is for a demo/kiosk type setup, you could just do the login in code, always using the same hard-coded credentials.

As for the other thing: if `hoodie.store.on()` only works intermittently for you, it would be great if you could post a bug report with steps to reproduce the problem at https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie/issues, also stating your OS, Hoodie and Node versions.

Comment: Cheers. As of the hoodie.on, i'm going to add the line hoodie.store.trigger to see if i manually trigger if it helps